# INSERT... SELECT... EXCEPT

Tags: mysql, sql, except

I am trying to combine two tables. So I would like to add the rows from table_2 into table_1 if the column_2 value not already exist in a row (also column_2) of table 1.

Something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_1 (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5)
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5 FROM table2
EXCEPT column_2 value already exists in a row in table 1
```

The value in column_2 is an ID. So I don't want to have two rows with identical IDs in table_1.

Comment: Consider adding debugging details into your post, including input tables definition and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

you need a query that has all the rows that should not be inserted for the `EXCEPT` part

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5) 
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5 FROM table_2 
EXCEPT
(SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5 FROM table_2 
WHERE column_2 IN ( SELECT column_2 FROm table_1))
```